# Использование нескольких форм в django python form

Tags: python, django

Надо вывести две формы с разных моделей, как их передать правильно и потом обработать?

код ниже выдает ошибку: *Reverse for 'order_add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['orders/add/(?P[^/]+)$']*

**views.py**

```
class OrderAddView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'   

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'formOne': SimpleOrderAddForm(), 'formTwo': FastOrderAddForm()}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('orders_home')

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tag'] = self.kwargs['tag']
        return context
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'order_add' tag %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formOne.non_field_errors }}
    {{ formOne.as_p }}
    {{ formTwo.non_field_errors }}
    {{ formTwo.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить заказ</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в том, что в методе get ты переопределяешь контекст и в итоге в шаблон не попадает `tag`. попробуй изменить метод get

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    context.update({'formOne': SimpleOrderAddForm(), 'formTwo': FastOrderAddForm()})
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

или наоборот, передавай формы в `get_context_data`

Comment: можете посмотреть этот вопрос, продолжение? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1254283/295536